# Arrays of composite types in PostgreSQL via NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, composite-types

I'm using Node.JS ("pg" package) to connect to a PostgreSQL database hosted on Heroku. I need to create a column in my table that will contain an array of different data types. By looking at other questions previously asked on Stackoverflow, I understand i can create composite data types that I can use to declare the array with. Like:

```
create type my_item as (
    field_1        text,
    field_2        text,
    field_3        text,
    field_4        number
);
```

However, I don't understand how to implement this when using Node.JS. Where do I put it in my files and at what point do I run it?

I have an `index.JS` file containing my Pool instance and the database access info. My functions are stored in a `models` folder. Each function has its own `SqlString` variable which is then passed to the query. Like:

```
export async function getScores() {
    const data = await query(`SELECT * FROM score`);
    return data.rows;
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `array of different composite types` in Postgresql. You might need to store the column as `json`/`jsonb` type instead and deal with them at the application level. Or create a superset type of all possible types in the array and deal with `NULL`s at the application level. That only works if the subset types don't overlap different types on the same key.
Also the main usecase for composites is related to `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` queries, aka anything that requires value interpolation from the application. Of course it's no use in your example code.